# ¿Cómo hago para que me quede alineado el párrafo con el título?

Tags: html, css, css3

Lo que tengo es una sangría de `100px` en el `h3` *"Recogidas sin costo"*

Puse debajo de el párrafo con muchas "a" pero al ejecutarlo, como pueden ver, la primera línea es la única que se adapta al `h3` pero las otras ¡NO!

Me gustaría que quedara algo así:

```
   RECOGIDAS SIN COSTO
   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Aquí les dejo el `CSS` y el `HTML`. Disculpen si todo esta desorganizado es que ando practicando. Espero me hayan entendido gracias.

```css
.acomo{
 text-indent: 100px;
 width: 500px;
 height: auto;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}

.acomo2{
 
 text-align: left;
 width: 450px;
 height: auto;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div  style="width: 1300px; height: 300px;"  class="red-cube">
   
   <h3 class="acomo">
   RECOGIDAS SIN COSTO
    <p class="acomo2"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    </p>
  </h3>      


  </div>
```

Comment: intenta exponer un poco mejor tu problema (o lo que esperas) para que te podamos ayudar mejor (entendiendo mejor la problemática). Te recomiendo que leas: [mcve].

Answer (score 6):

Podrías simplemente reemplazar `text-indent` (*que solo afecta al primer renglón*) por `margin-left` (*que afecta a la caja completa*)

#### Ejemplo:

```css
.acomo {
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.acomo2 {
  text-align: left;
  width: 450px;
  height: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 1300px; height: 300px;" class="red-cube">
  <h3 class="acomo">
    RECOGIDAS SIN COSTO
    <p class="acomo2"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    </p>
  </h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

La estructura es mejorable y se están aplicando estilos de manera poco hortodoxa. Creo que una buena optimización del código sería:

```
.red-cube {
  width: 1300px; 
  height: 300px;
}

.estiloContendor {
  padding: 3em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
}

.acomo {
  /*estilo solo para h3*/
}

.acomo2 {
  text-align: left;
  height: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
}

<div class="red-cube">
  <div class="estiloContendor">
  <h3 class="acomo">RECOGIDAS SIN COSTO</h3>
    <p class="acomo2"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```